# Midori displays mobile sites

Tags: midori

I've installed Midori to work in an Elementary mockup. Midori works just fine, but, on a few domains, it opens mobile websites instead of the regular pages. A of now, this happens with gmail.com, facebook.com, paginegialle.it, and others; yet other websites which do have a mobile version, as gazzetta.it, show the regular version. I couldn't find a solution through settings and I didn't find any mention of this problem on forums or else, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Probably because of Midori problems, at least I read some articles (from 2009 or so, though) that Midori is not mature enough for displaying many "advanced" sites. Maybe some detection code of these sites decide then it's not an "advanced" browser, so it will fall back on the more basic mode instead. A quick google on this topic shows that many people says this, though I am not sure since I don't use Midori. So treat my comment as only a hint, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since i have not used midori i cannot be sure, but from reviews, it is possible to change the user agent in midori. switch the user agent in Edit - preferencces -network to something like firefox and you issue may be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I use midori as my default browser, and after that I set "identify as Safari" and all problems were fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell Midori to "Identify as iPhone." Perhaps this is set. Check in **Preferences** > **Network** tab > **Identify as** drop-down menu.

[image: Identify as iPhone setting in Midori]

Comment: Why on earth Midori will identify itself as iphone unless I configured it?